# DeviceAdminReceiver for Android O

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, device-admin

Helo,

As is described [Broadcast Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts) Android O comes with some limitations on implicit broadcasts, by definition broadcasts received by DeviceAdminReceiver are implicit also it are not in [Implicit Broadcast Exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html), although however, MyDeviceAdminReceiver continue receives broadcasts without dynamic registration.

Should I consider that it are explicit broadcasts ?, or it should be dynamically registered ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I consider that it is explicit broadcasts ?

Yes. Just because an `Intent` has an action string does not make it implicit. What makes it implicit is *not* having a `ComponentName` or package to constrain where the `Intent` gets broadcast.

In this case, since not everything can listen to those broadcasts, the system is filtering the list of registrants to those eligible to receive them, and is using explicit `Intents` to only send the broadcast to the eligible receivers.